# Incorrect image being shown on java script slider bar trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The sliders show a different badge depending on the combined values. I've 2 questions.

## 1 -There is a "var img = 'snackapp.png';" line, which is currently showing as a value and I dont understand what purpose it performs in the code. Is it needed? The badge its linked to is displaying in the code, which i dont want it to.

## 2 Also the badge is not always updating after the the sliders have been moved for the second time. How do I resolve this?

```
           <html lang="en">
   <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Do I need a treat>!?</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   </head>
  <body>
   <p>
    <label for="amount">Volume:</label>
    <img id="amount-img" src="img/snackapp.png"/>
  </p>
  <style>
    .slider { height: 200px; float:left; margin-right:20px; }
  </style>
  <div class="slider"></div>
   <div class="slider"></div>
   <div class="slider"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>

   <script>
   $(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.slider').each( function() {
        total += $(this).slider('value');
    });

    var img = 'snackapp.png';
    if( total>=499) img = 'booze.png';
    else if( total>=400 ) img = 'fishandchips.png';
    else if( total>=300 ) img = 'pizza.png';
    else if( total>=200 ) img = 'doughnut.png';
    else if( total>=100 ) img = 'choc.png';
    else if( total>=99 ) img = 'icecream.png';
    else if( total<=98 ) img = 'fruit.png';
    else if( total<=97 ) img = 'hotdrink.png';

    ;

    $('#amount-img').attr( 'src', 'img/'+img );
    }
    });
    });


   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I dont want this to happen`. what it mean?

Comment: Can you produce the jsFiddle that will make you more clear.

Comment: I've updated the question above as a first step.

Comment: Can you post some html to give the script and the errors some context?

Comment: I've added the complete code.

Comment: Everything seems to work ok here http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/q2fvB/, except for the fact that your last condition `total<=97` will never be met as you already have `total<=98` before it

Comment: Would that resolve is I changed it to 
else if( total>=60 ) img = 'fruit.png';
else if( total<=59 ) img = 'hotdrink.png';

Comment: And if you do not want to show the contents of `img`, remove this line: `$('#result').text('img/' + img);`. `img` is needed because it contains the current source for `#amount-img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var img = 'snackapp.png';` seems to be the default image and the reason why it is declared is to be the equivalent of an else clause to that if statement. If none of the conditions of the if statement are met then `img` remains `snackapp.png`.

I had no problem with the "badge" updating each time a slider was moved. You realize that the slider has to be moved over a certain threshhold in order to make the image change right?. The image is changing depending on the total value of all the sliders joined together.

If you dont want the `snackapp.png` to be displayed either change it with a default image of your own or modify your code to

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <label for="amount">Volume:</label>
    <img id="amount-img" src="img/hotdrink.png" />
</p>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $(".slider").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var total = 0;
            $('.slider').each(function () {
                total += $(this).slider('value');
            });

            var img = 'snackapp.png';
            if (total >= 499) img = 'booze.png';
            else if (total >= 400) img = 'fishandchips.png';
            else if (total >= 300) img = 'pizza.png';
            else if (total >= 200) img = 'doughnut.png';
            else if (total >= 100) img = 'choc.png';
            else if (total >= 99) img = 'icecream.png';
            else if (total >= 50) img = 'fruit.png';
            else if (total < 50) img = 'hotdrink.png';

            $('#amount-img').attr('src', 'img/' + img);
        }
    });
});
```

which will make hotdrink the default image.